# AJAX : passing multiple variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Passing one variable works :

```
var type = $.cookie('liste-voyage-type');   
var code=  $.cookie('liste-voyage-code');       

$.ajax({
     url : '../listing-voyage-produit.php',
     type : 'GET' ,
     data : 'type=' + type;
 });
```

listing-voyage-produit.php

```
$type = $_GET['type'];
echo 'type' . $type;  // => 2
```

But I cannot make it working with 2 variables:

```
$.ajax({
  url : '../listing-voyage-produit.php',
  type : 'GET' ,
  data : 'type=' + type+'&code=' + code;
});
```

listing-voyage-produit.php

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
echo 'code' . $code;      //   => !?
```

Comment: check the ajax request using browser network tab to see whether the parameters are sent properly

Comment: What is the value of `code`? If it contains any special characters you need to encode it with `encodeURIComponent`. But it's better to give `$.ajax` an object, and it will do all the encoding for you.

Comment: Remove the semi-colon after type in ajax call

Comment: @Arun P Johny response is ok

Comment: @Barmar code is like Z3\_P9\_ and it might the be problem coz passing the single variable code does not work. i have tried code=encodeURIComponent(code) and this does not work

Comment: @PaparazzoKid That question uses POST, not GET

Comment: And the answers use what this question is trying to do. So I don't see how they can explain what he's doing wrong.

Comment: @Matoeil Have you fixed the extraneous semi-colons?

Comment: @Barmar so u mean data : 'code=' + code+'&type='+type      .it gives typeundefinedcodeundefined

Comment: I mean there should not be a `;` between `data : 'type=' + type+'&code=' + code` and `}`.

Comment: That semicolon should be causing a syntax error, so none of the code should run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need not to convert data into string parameters. Jquery will do that for you. Try this

```
var type = $.cookie('liste-voyage-type'); 
var code=  $.cookie('liste-voyage-code');     

var myData = {
  type: type,
  code: code
};

$.ajax({
   url : '../listing-voyage-produit.php',
   type : 'GET' ,
   data : myData
});
```

Comment: The data should be percent-encoded, not JSON. If you just pass the object to `$.ajax` it will do that automatically.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for correction..I made another type there..Wrote data instead of myData

Comment: Use `console.log(myData)` before making ajax call and tell the output

Comment: @blunderboy  damn! it gives Object { type=undefined, code=undefined}

Comment: There you go...Get the values first and passing object in ajax call as I explained in the answer will fix everything.

Comment: @blunderboy thanks . so i have to make sure type and code are string?

Comment: @Matoeil Not necessarily strings..numbers or any primitive type will do fine. Just make sure they are not undefined..

Comment: @blunderboy  thanx now the response is Object { type="1", code="Z3\_P95\_"}  . how i can retrieve these datas as 2 php string variables?

Comment: @Matoeil Rest of the code should work fine. See my answer and Just remove `;` after type and data in your ajax call as others have already mentioned.

Comment: ok for some reasons the $type = $_GET['type'];
echo 'type' . $type; and code does not display the corresponding response

Answer (score 1):

use `data: {'q1': data1,'q2':data2}`

```
var type = $.cookie('liste-voyage-type'); 
var code=  $.cookie('liste-voyage-code'); 

$.ajax({ url: 'myscript.php',
  data: {'q1': type,'q2':code},
  type: 'post',
  success: function(output) {
    alert(output);
  }
});
```

#### myscript.php

```
<?php
  $type = $_POST['q1'];
  $code = $_POST['q2'];
  echo $type . "_____" . $code;
?>
```