# jQuery Ajax : send data storing in a variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I need to send the **JSON** data in a jQuery's ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{"assessmentId":1,"pageId":1,"currentPage":2}',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
    // TO DO
    }
});
```

This is working fine but the data I am sending needs to be stored in a variable like this:

```
var jsonSendingData = '{"assessmentId":1,"pageId":1,"currentPage":2}';
```

Once I keep it in a variable jsonSendingData and pass in ajax call, it gives me error.

I also tried to stringify the json data like this:

```
var jsonSendingData = JSON.stringify([{"assessmentId":1,"pageId":1,"currentPage":2}]);
```

It does not work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: which quotes and where? can you please write that string?

Comment: When you called `stringify` you added an extra pair of array-brackets on the outside. You're stringifying `[{...}]` instead of `{...}` and that difference will be faithfully passed on to the server. Apparently the server doesn't like it.

Comment: @jeewan The quotes when storing to variable. See answer.

Comment: I think this is very similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20571576/1310070

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to send the data as a string, `jQuery` will do that for you. Try this

```js
var myData = {
  assessmentId: 1,
  pageId: 1,
  currentPage: 2
};

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: myData, //Notice the change here
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      // TO DO
    }
});
```

PS: There is a very [similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20571576/1310070). Please check that.

Comment: I need to send a variable in data's value like this:

data : myJsonData,

I already mentioned above that, the code you wrote already working.

Comment: @jeewan Take a look at updated answer. You are making an error by wrapping json in quotes

Comment: I tried this but you missed to stringify myData before sending. So, finally, this worked:

myData = JSON.stringify(myDaya); 

Thanks :-)

Comment: Glad that you could find out yourself even with very small help..:)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the quotes when storing in variable.

```
var jsonSendingData = {
    assessmentId:1,
    pageId:1,
    currentPage:2
};

jQuery.ajax({
       url:url,
       type:'POST',
       data:jsonSendingData
  }).done(function(data){
   console.log(data);
 });
```

Otherwise you have to specify it in the request headers

```
var datastring = JSON.stringify(jsonSendingData);

data: datastring,
contentType: "application/json",
```